# why is my compare evaluating to false

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, character

I'm new to javascript.  I am writing an function to check if a palindrome can be obtained from it by at most one swap of some pair of characters. one problem i am having is that my object seems to look correct in the alerts, but it is evaluating to false no matter what operator I use.  I attached a fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/sQx4H/89/

What am I doing wrong?

```
function isOneSwapEnough() {
inputString = 'aabaa'
    var inputStringArray = inputString.split();
    if (isPalandrome(inputStringArray))
    {
        return true;
    }
    //if we made it this far then the string is not a palendrone yet.
    var newCharArray;
    for (var j =0; j<inputStringArray.length; j++)
    {
        newCharArray = inputStringArray; 
        for (var k =0; k<inputStringArray.length; k++)
        {
            var tempChar =  inputStringArray[j];
            newCharArray[j] = newCharArray[k];
            newCharArray[k] = tempChar;

            if (isPalandrome(newCharArray))
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}

function isPalandrome(testString)
{
    var firstcheck = [];
    // already a char array... var testStringArray = testString.split();
    //check if already a palendrone
    for (var i =0; i<testString.length; i++)
    {

        firstcheck[testString.length-(i+1)] = testString[i];
        //console.log(testString[i]);
        //console.log(firstcheck[testString.length-i]);
    }
    //console.log(testString);
    //console.log(firstcheck);
    //alert("1: " + typeof  testString);
    //alert("2: " + typeof  firstcheck);
    alert("condition " + firstcheck.valueOf() === testString.valueOf())
    if ( firstcheck.valueOf() == testString.valueOf())
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Just so you know, `'aabaa'.split() //=> ['aabaa']` not `['a', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'a']` like you're probably expecting. You might want to try `.split('')`, if that's the case

Comment: do your palindromes allow for spaces, commas, or other special characters?

Comment: The line `alert("condition " + firstcheck.valueOf() === testString.valueOf())` will always return false.  It will concatenate `"condition"` with `firstCheck.valueOf()` and compare it against `testString.valueOf()`, which will always be `false`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### code review

Apart from the comment I left on your question, there's a lot going on with your `isPalindrome` procedure; my comments inline …

```
// `isPalindrome` is a nice function name
// `testString` is a terrible parameter name,
// especially since you're passing in an array
function isPalandrome(testString)
{
    // unclear variable name
    var firstcheck = [];

    // by the end of this loop, firstcheck will be a testString in reverse
    // ok, got it
    for (var i = 0; i<testString.length; i++)
    {
        firstcheck[testString.length-(i+1)] = testString[i];
    }
    // the short version of this code is
    var firstcheck = testString.slice(0).reverse()

    // this doesn't do what you think it does
    // `[1,2,3] === [1,2,3]` is false in javascript
    // you cannot compare arrays like that
    if ( firstcheck.valueOf() == testString.valueOf())
    {
        // `if (condition) { return true }` is bad code
        // just use `return condition`
        return true;
    }
    // don't worry, you don't have to compare arrays to check for your palindromes
}
```

#### quick & dirty solution

This doesn't work if there are spaces or special characters in the input string, but your question gives no indication of such criteria. So maybe this is all you're looking for.

You do *not* have to compare arrays to detect a palindrome.

```js
function isPalindrome(str) {
  return str === str.split('').reverse().join('')
}

console.log(isPalindrome('aabaa')) // true
console.log(isPalindrome('racecar')) // true
console.log(isPalindrome('risetovotesir')) // true
console.log(isPalindrome('sorry but not a palindrome')) // false
```

#### character swapping

As for the character swapping bit, you have a bit of a problem on your hands there. What are eligible swaps? Can a character only trade places with its immediate neighbour? Or can any two characters be swapped?

```
input | posssibile swaps
------+------------------------------------------------------------
a     |
ab    | ba
abc   | bac cba acb
abcd  | bacd cbad dbca acbd adcb abdc
abcde | bacde cbade dbcae ebcda acbde adcbe aecdb abdce abedc abced
```

As you can see, *possible swaps* grows quickly. Total possible swaps can be computed as

```
((n - 1) * n / 2), where n = length of input
```

For example, a string length of *5* will have *10* possible swaps …

```
((5 - 1) * 5 / 2) = 10
```

A string length of *20* will have *190* possible swaps. (Relevant: in this situation, `n` is a [triangular number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number))

Can you come up with a basic procedure which generates and checks each of the possible swaps?

Either way, I still don't think you need arrays for this. I would start by writing a generic `charSwap` procedure that returns a string with swapped chars. Something like this maybe …

```js
function charSwap(str, x, y) {
  function slice(from,to) {
    return str.substring(from,to)
  }
  let a = str[x], b = str[y]
  return slice(0,x) + b + slice(x+1,y) + a + slice(y+1)
}

console.log(charSwap('abcde',0,1)) // bacde 
console.log(charSwap('abcde',0,2)) // cbade 
console.log(charSwap('abcde',0,3)) // dbcae 
console.log(charSwap('abcde',0,4)) // ebcda 

console.log(charSwap('abcde',1,2)) // acbde 
console.log(charSwap('abcde',1,3)) // adcbe 
console.log(charSwap('abcde',1,4)) // aecdb 

console.log(charSwap('abcde',2,3)) // abdce 
console.log(charSwap('abcde',2,4)) // abedc 

console.log(charSwap('abcde',3,4)) // abced
```

I'm sure you're probably picking up a pattern there by the end. Then I would use `charSwap` in `isOneSwapEnough`. I'll leave it up to you to write the loop for it though. I can give you a little bit of skeleton code to get started …

```
function isOneSwapEnough(str) {
  // setup loop
  // let x and y be variables for character indexes to swap
  // begin loop
    if (isPalindrome(charSwap(str, x, y)))
      return true
    else
      // continue loop
  // end loop
  return false
}
```

Comment: I really like your solution, especially making a function that swaps two characters in a string to make the code simpler.

Comment: @kamoroso94 I'm glad you like it. Reducing complexity (making code simpler) plays a lead role in writing sane code.

Answer (score -1):

I believe it may have to do with the fact that you are trying to do a direct array comparison. The method below will trip to true though I'm not sure if it's what your looking for.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/juliusplaras/sQx4H/92/)

```
if (JSON.stringify(firstcheck) == JSON.stringify(testString)) {
    return true;
}
```